# Assign multiple IPs to same docker container using macvlan (or by any other method)

Tags: docker, networking, iptables, static-ip-address, macvlan

I have currently 2 networks created using macvlan over running over my synology. These networks are physically seprated and completely isolated. So device on one network can not communicate to other.

```
root@syno:/# docker network ls
NETWORK ID      NAME               DRIVER              SCOPE
12434567        priNet             macvlan             local
76543210        secNet             macvlan             local
```

I am using these networks as my primary home network and other for my smart home devices. I am able to attach any docker container to any of them. However, now I would like to attach some containers to both of them.
So I updated my docker-compose to attach container to both networks.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  container:
    image: someImage:latest
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
    volumes:
       - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    restart: always
    networks:
      int_homeNet:
        ipv4_address: 192.1.1.21
      int_smartNet:
        ipv4_address: 192.1.2.21
        
networks:
  int_homeNet:
    external: true
    name: priNet
  int_smartNet:
    external: true
    name: secNet
```

After running this docker compose file, I get following error

```
level=fatal msg=\\\\\\\"failed to add interface dockerb21a0fc to sandbox: error setting interface \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"dockerb21a0fc\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" IP to 192.168.2.21/24: cannot program address 192.168.2.21/24 in sandbox interface because it conflicts with existing route {Ifindex: 194 Dst: 192.168.176.0/22 Src: 192.168.1.21 Gw: <nil> Flags: [] Table: 254}\\\\\\\"\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown
```

Do you think if what I am doing is right way to do it ? Or am I doing any failure ? I am also fine to achive same thing by some other way...

Many thanks for your all of your suggestions...